# Get a JSON Documents based on some properties of JSON

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Suppose a MongoCollection has 2 Documents as shown below

```
{"employee_id": "1", {"name":"A","age":"18"}}
```

and

```
{"employee_id": "2", {"name":"B","age":"18"}}
```

How can I query this Collection such that it would return me the first Document using only `employee_id`

Using the following Maven Entries

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example docs you supplied are not valid JSON; they seem to contain two values `"1"` and `{"name":"A","age":"18"}` but only one key: `"employee_id"`.

Assuming ...

- The valid document format is:

  ```
  {"employee_id": "1", "details": {"name":"A","age":"18"}}
  ```
- You are looking for guidance on using the Mongo Java Driver (this assumption is based on your inclusion of the Maven co-ordinates for that driver).

Then, the following code shows how to find the first document by filtering on `employee_id`:

```
@Test
public void canRead() {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClientFactory().create();

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("stackoverflow").getCollection("sample");

    // this test assumes that the two documents you showed in your question have already been written to the collection e.g.
    // collection.insertOne(Document.parse("{\"employee_id\": \"1\", \"details\": {\"name\":\"A\",\"age\":\"18\"}}"));
    // collection.insertOne(Document.parse("{\"employee_id\": \"2\", \"details\": {\"name\":\"B\",\"age\":\"18\"}}"));

    Bson filter = Filters.eq("employee_id", "1");
    Assert.assertEquals(1, collection.count(filter));

    Document document = collection.find(filter).first();
    Assert.assertEquals("1", document.get("employee_id"));
    Document details = (Document) document.get("details");
    Assert.assertEquals("A", details.get("name"));
    // age is a string?!
    Assert.assertEquals("18", details.get("age"));
}
```